# Why have I this error on c++ using my classes?

Tags: c++, class

I'm making a math engine using c++ and I created 3 classes (vector, matrix and quaternion).When I compile my code using g++ I have an error and I don't know how to fixit, if someone can help me it would be appreciated.

Here is my vector.hpp code:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include "quaternion.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

namespace helix{
    class vector{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        ...
        
        vector();
        vector(float x, float y, float z);
        vector(const vector& vec);

        ...
    }
}
```

Here is my terminal output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "helix::vector::vector(float, float, float)", referenced from:
      _main in main-efde0e.o
  "helix::vector::~vector()", referenced from:
      _main in main-efde0e.o
```

If you need more informations, ask me !]

**[ You can access source code on my GitHub: https://github.com/miishuriinu/game_engine ]**

Comment: The linker can't find the function implementation. Did you write an implementation for the constructors?

Comment: Include the full, minimised code needed to replicate the error _in the question_, not ellipsised or only available via external links.

Comment: side note: never use the same name for member variables and function parameters: it's an headache at best, a bug likely

Comment: @Nina Yup, you can see my code on my GitHub

Comment: @GianPaolo Thanks! I changed that in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Makefile` only compiles `main.cpp`: it only uses the compiler as follows

```
g++ -std=c++17 src/main.cpp -o bin/pgm -I include -L lib -l glfw.3.3 -l GLEW.2.2.0 -framework OpenGL
```

You need to compile and link the other cpp files in `src/maths` as well, since the methods are defined there.

Comment: How can I do that ? @chi

Comment: @miishuriinu You should find some "compile & link" Makefile tutorial, there should be many. Anyways, to do that without a Makefile one runs `g++ -c file1.cpp`, `g++ -c file2.cpp`, ... to compile (this will produce a bunch of .o files), and then links everything as `g++ -o executable_name file1.o file2.o ...`. A Makefile usually reproduces these steps with the correct dependencies so to avoid recompiling what did not change.